# Postgres pg_upgrade fails

Tags: postgresql

I would like to upgrade postgresql from v11 to v15.

I set up everything according to this :
(note: I am within a bitnami helmchart so os-version is upgraded too from Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) to Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye))

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/8025#issuecomment-964906018
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html

**my final command is:**

```
gosu postgres pg_upgrade -c -b /bitnami/postgresql/oldbin -B /opt/bitnami/postgresql/bin -d /bitnami/postgresql/olddata -D /bitnami/postgresql/data
```

**result:**

```
/bitnami/postgresql/oldbin/postgres: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.63: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
no data was returned by command ""/bitnami/postgresql/oldbin/postgres" -V"

check for "/bitnami/postgresql/oldbin/postgres" failed: cannot execute
Failure, exiting
```

when I run manually: `/bitnami/postgresql/oldbin/postgres -V`
I get : `error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.63: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Is that some kind of a postgres-OS incompatibility stuff? If so how can I use the pg_upgrade command?

**update**:
Ok I tried to run postgres -V with the following setups:

```
postgres 11 on Debian GNU/Linux 11   -> fails
postgres 15 on Debian GNU/Linux 10   -> fails
postgres 11 on Debian GNU/Linux 10   -> works
postgres 15 on Debian GNU/Linux 11   -> works
```

So now the question is basically how to upgrade from postgres 11 to 15 on Debian/Linux 11 using pg_upgrade?

Comment: That looks like your installation is broken: either relevant libraries are missing, or the shared library path is messed up. At any rate, that problem is related to server administration and not to software development.

Comment: I'm guessing that's an old "libicu" that has been removed during the OS upgrade. If you get PostgreSQL from the project's own apt repos (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) you should be able to run both versions of postgresql on Debian 11. Do the OS upgrade and PG upgrade in separate steps of course.